# Parallelized load odbc in Stata

Tags: parallel-processing, odbc, stata

I am trying to so parallelize loading data through an ODBC connection in Stata using the parallel command from SSC.

Here's a toy example file myloop.do, which loops over two ids:

```
#delimit;

foreach id in 77860668 1124831359 {;
    odbc load, exec(`"
    SELECT
        user_slctd_id
        ,user_id
        FROM dw_table
    WHERE user_id =`id'
    "') dsn("my_dsn") lowercase sqlshow clear;

    save "id_`id'.dta", replace;
};
```

This works nicely. However, when I try to run this code in parallel like this:

```
parallel setclusters 2
parallel do "myloop.do"
```

It hangs on "Waiting for the clusters to finish."

**How do I diagnose what's going wrong? Is there a better way to pull data in parallel and append all the files together?**

I am using version 1.14.6.17 17jun2014 version of parallel module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what's going on with parallel behind scenes, you should use the keep option like this:

```
parallel setclusters 2
parallel do "myloop.do", keep
```

This will tell parallel that it should not remove the auxiliary files (among them the logfile).

Also, if you are up to, you can always checkout the lastest version of it at the project repo
http://github.com/gvegayon/parallel

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: An update, now you can use the `parallel append` command. You can check it out getting the new version (1.15.8.19 19ago2015, already in SSC), or at the project repo

https://github.com/gvegayon/parallel/blob/master/ado/parallel.sthlp#L384-L443

Comment: The problem was that myloop.do cannot be semicolon-delimited. The keep option allowed me to diagnose that. Is there any way to get parallel to work with such files so that I don't have to reformat it?

Comment: We can take a look, if you could include more details by adding a new issue in the project's website https://github.com/gvegayon/parallel/issues it'll be great. In the meantime, perhaps you could try to explicitly use `set delim` at  the beginning and end of the file.

Comment: I added an example issue at github. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

What ODBC Driver are you using?  To which database type?

This almost sounds like a situation where the driver may only be able to handle a single statement per connection.  It's hard to say without knowing what is happening at the driver level.

I would suggest create an ODBC trace to see what the ODBC calls are doing at the time of the hang.  Check for any underlying errors that may be a root cause for the "wait" message.

Check your driver documentation for specifics surrounding number of statements per connection and threading; in case that may be a factor.